# Custom table creation

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have made a database using dbhelper previously, and now I want to add a table in that using this code. But I am getting error that no such table found. Please can you help me out with this.

Should I need to open database every time and can I make two tables in using a single `dbHelper` class for two different activities.

```
package com.example.kunj.scope;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase;
import static com.example.kunj.scope.ScopeDBHelper.CREATE_TABLE;
import static com.example.kunj.scope.ScopeDBHelper.DATABASE_NAME;
import static com.example.kunj.scope.ScopeDBHelper.DATABASE_VERSION;


/**
 * Created by kunj on 2/8/2018.
 */

public class CustomScopeDBHelper {


    public Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ScopeOpenHelper scopeOpenHelper;
    String DBPATH;
    public CustomScopeDBHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        scopeOpenHelper = new ScopeOpenHelper(context);
       // this.DBPATH = this.context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
      //  Log.e("Path 1", DBPATH);
        db = scopeOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    public static String query;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scope.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    String TABLE_NAME;

  public void getQuery(List<String> columnName, String tableName) {
        TABLE_NAME = tableName;
        /*int i = columnName.size();
        int count = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String str : columnName) {
            count++;
            if (sb.length() == 0) {
                sb.append("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( ID text, ");
            }
            if (count != (i)) {
                sb.append(str + " " + "text,");
            } else {
                sb.append(str + " " + "text);");
            }
        }

        query = (sb.toString()); */
               query = "create table "+ TABLE_NAME +" ( col1 text, col2 text, col3 text, col4, text);";
      //  CREATE_TABLE= "create table "+tableName+" ( "+"id"+ " text, "+"col1"+" text , "+"col2"+" text, " +"col3"+" text , "+"col4"+" text );";

    }

    void addEntry(List<String> data,GenericDTO genericDTO)
    {

        List<Object> cols = genericDTO.getAttributeValues("custom_expense");
     //   System.out.println("Cols:"+cols.size());
     //   System.out.println("Data"+data.size());
       //List<String> columnName = new ArrayList<>();
        int size = data.size();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        for(int i =0; i<size;i++) {
           //Toast.makeText(context, cols.get(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            values.put(cols.get(i).toString(), data.get(i));
          /*  values.put("col1","a");
            values.put("col2","a");
            values.put("col3","a");
            values.put("col4","a");*/


        }
        long res = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);


        //long res = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        if (res == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    private  class ScopeOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        String DBPATH;
        Context ctx;
        public ScopeOpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(query);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

                 }
    }
}
```

package com.example.kunj.scope;

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by kunj on 1/23/2018.
 */
public class CustomizeFragment extends Fragment {
    Dialog dialog;
    Button addbtn;
    EditText data1,data2,data3,data4;
    ListView customlistview;
    CustomScopeDBHelper customScopeDBHelper;
    GenericDTO genericDTO;
    ScopeDBHelper scopeDBHelper;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_frg,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        customlistview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.customlistview);
        customScopeDBHelper = new CustomScopeDBHelper(getActivity());
        addbtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
        scopeDBHelper = new ScopeDBHelper(getActivity());

        data1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.data1);
        data2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.data2);
        data3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.data3);
        data4 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.data4);
        genericDTO = new GenericDTO();

        addbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String dataOne = data1.getText().toString();
                final String dataTwo = data2.getText().toString();
                final String dataThree = data3.getText().toString();
                final String dataFour = data4.getText().toString();

                List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
                data.add(dataOne);
                data.add(dataTwo);
                data.add(dataThree);
                data.add(dataFour);
                List<String> columnList = new ArrayList<String>();
                columnList.add("col1");
                columnList.add("col2");
                columnList.add("col3");
                columnList.add("col4");
                String TABLE_NAME = "custom_expense";
                customScopeDBHelper.getQuery(columnList, TABLE_NAME);
                for(String s:columnList)
                genericDTO.addAttribute(TABLE_NAME,s);


                customScopeDBHelper.addEntry(data,genericDTO);

            }
        });
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                dialog.setTitle("Create Record");
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialog);
                Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                dialog.show();






            }
        });
    }
```

Main DBHelper class in which main database is made is running perfectly:

```
   package com.example.kunj.scope;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by kunj on 10/8/2017.
 */

public class ScopeDBHelper {

    public  static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scope.db";
    public  static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_EXPENSE = "expense_table";
   // public static final String TABLE_ATTENDANCE = "attendance_table";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID= "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY= "CATEGORY";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION= "DESCRIPTION";
    public static final String COLUMN_AMOUNT= "AMOUNT";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE= "DATE";

    public  final String CREATE_TABLE= "create table "+TABLE_EXPENSE+" ( "+COLUMN_ID+ " text, "+COLUMN_CATEGORY+" text , "+COLUMN_DESCRIPTION+" text, " +COLUMN_AMOUNT+" text , "+COLUMN_DATE+" date );";


    public Context context;
    ScopeOpenHelper scopeOpenHelper;
    public static SQLiteDatabase db;

    public ScopeDBHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        scopeOpenHelper = new ScopeOpenHelper(context);
        db = scopeOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    void addExpense(Expense expense){



        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORY, expense.getCategory());
        values.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, expense.getDescription());
        values.put(COLUMN_AMOUNT,expense.getAmount());
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE, expense.getDate());

        long res = db.insert(TABLE_EXPENSE,null,values);

        /*if(res == -1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }*/

    }

        List<Expense> getallExpenses()
    {
        List<Expense> expenses = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_EXPENSE,null,null,null,null,null,null);

        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                String category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CATEGORY));
                String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION));
                String amount = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_AMOUNT));
                String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DATE));

                expenses.add(new Expense(category,description,amount,date) );

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        return expenses;
    }

    public int deleteExpense(Expense ex) {

        return db.delete(TABLE_EXPENSE,COLUMN_DESCRIPTION+"=?",new String[]{ex.description});
    }


    private  class ScopeOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public ScopeOpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            //System.out.print(CREATE_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

        }
    }

}
```

The fragment which uses the database is:

```
 package com.example.kunj.scope;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by kunj on 1/23/2018.
 */
public class ExpenseFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    Dialog dialog;
    Spinner categorySpinner;
    ArrayAdapter<String> categoryAdapter;
    EditText descriptionEt,amountEt,dateEt;
    Button addbtn,clearbtn,intentbtn;
    ScopeDBHelper scopeDBHelper;
    List<Expense> expenses;
    ListView expenselistview;
    ExpenseAdapter expenseAdapter;
    Calendar myCalendar;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.expense_frg,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        expenselistview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.expenselistview);
        scopeDBHelper =  new ScopeDBHelper(getActivity());
        expenses = scopeDBHelper.getallExpenses();

        expenseAdapter = new ExpenseAdapter((HomePage) getActivity(),expenses);
        expenselistview.setAdapter(expenseAdapter);
        expenselistview.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
        myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();


        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel();


            }

        };


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                dialog.setTitle("Add Expense");
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialog);
                Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                dialog.show();

                categorySpinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.category);
                descriptionEt= (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.description);
                amountEt = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.amount);
                dateEt = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.date);
                addbtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
                clearbtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.clearbtn);

                String items [] ={"Entertainment","Food","Movie","Goods","Fuel","Other"};


                categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,items);
                categorySpinner.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);




                dateEt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        //        Toast.makeText(HomePage.this,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                    }
                });

                addbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        final String categorystrng = categorySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        final String descriptionstrng = descriptionEt.getText().toString();
                        final String amountstrng = amountEt.getText().toString();
                        final String datestrng = dateEt.getText().toString();

                        /*if(categorystrng.isEmpty())
                        {
                            categoryEt.setError("Mandatory field");
                            return;
                        }*/
                        if(descriptionstrng.isEmpty())
                        {
                            descriptionEt.setError("Mandatory field");
                            return;
                        }
                        if(amountstrng.isEmpty())
                        {
                            amountEt.setError("Mandatory field");return;
                        }



                        Expense expense = new Expense(categorystrng,descriptionstrng,amountstrng,datestrng);
                        //Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, categorystrng,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        scopeDBHelper.addExpense(expense);
                        expenseAdapter.addExpense(expense);
                        expenseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });


            }
        });

    }

    private void updateLabel() {
        String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

        dateEt.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

       final Expense ex = expenses.get(i);

        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        dialog.setTitle("Delete Expense");
        dialog.setMessage("Do you want to delete this entry?");


        dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                if(scopeDBHelper.deleteExpense(ex)==1)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Expense Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    expenseAdapter.delete(ex);
                    expenseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Couldn't delete this entry",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


            }
        });

        dialog.show();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question, why isn't your `CustomScopeDBHelper` class extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`? See: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html#java

Comment: Because I have made a different class called ScopeOpenHelper at the end which extends the SQLiteOpenhelper and it's methods.

Comment: Personally I would move everything inside `ScopeOpenHelper` and make it the main class, getting rid of `CustomScopeDBHelper`. The scope and structure of that class seems a bit all over the place as it currently stands.

Comment: Can you tell me that can I make two tables from two different activities in same database?

Comment: In short, yes. My answer will be a bit long so I don't have time to write it out yet. Give me a couple of hours.

Comment: Yes I am waiting and i have updated my code you can also have a look at it and the whole project is at :  https://github.com/KunjDesai96/FinalYearPorject

Comment: I have tried all this but still not working, so can you please do the necessary changes in the git link if you find out the solution... please?